# how to filter by month from template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm attempting to channel a datetime field by month and year. Though no one can really say why while entering both month and year I get back a vacant set returned.

Model

```
class SpareParts(models.Model):
vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
amount = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
```

And i want to filter on the basis of vehicle and month vise and here is mine view
VIEWS.py

```
def view_spare(request):
sparepart = SpareParts.objects.all()
vehicle_filter = request.POST.get('vehicle')   # get the value of the date field
month_filter = request.POST.get('month')   # get the value of the date field
if vehicle_filter:
    if month_filter:
        sparepart = sparepart.filter(vehicle=vehicle_filter,date__month=month_filter).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
        return render(request,'invoice/spare_parts_list.html',{'sparepart':sparepart})
```

and i want render the whole month sum of amount in template

Answer (score 1):

date__month is an integer and according to your explanation “month” is a date field. So, you cannot compare them. You have to calculate the month and the year of your date input:

Do this:

```
import datetime
month_filter = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.request.POST.get('month'),"%d/%m/%Y").date() #Change with the formar that you are using.
```

And:

```
sparepart = sparepart.filter(vehicle=vehicle_filter,date__month=month_filter.month, date__year=month_filter.year).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: Thank you, but  this is not resolve because html date tag return different time so which html tag i will use for those query

Comment: Can you share your html code?